# Unable to view update the parameters of Agent population

Tags: anylogic

I have agents population as "MyAgents" and I am trying to update the parameters during the process flow.  pic shows that I am updating parameter with value of 1
[image]

Then in the below simple function trying to sum it up but it is not giving any value.

[image]

I have traced the parameter value in the sink block and it can viewed there but when I am using function to sum up it is giving zero output.

My goal is to update parameters on the entry or exit of block.
Is here a way to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're updating the parameter once the agent enters the sink. After an agent enters the sink, it will be removed from the population. So the population *myAgents* will not contain the agent with the updated parameter value and thus the sum will always be zero.

Instead, I would suggest to create a global variable `total_amount` (e.g. in Main) and change the code "*on enter*" at the sink to (if the total_amount should be incremented by 1):

```
total_amount++;
```

Or if the total_amount should be incremented by a given value:

```
total_amount += <parameter_value>;
```